# JS lp-solver. How to use all the products at least once?

Tags: javascript, constraints, linear-programming

I made a linear program code for a diet app that minimizes the cost of products while meeting user's desired calories. It is working, at least somewhat working. The problem is that the result is made by using only the one, best product out of all products to get the lowest cost and meet the user's calories. I want to make it to use all of the products (if possible -> doesn't go over user's calories) at least once. I've tried to add some constraints to the model, but that didn't fix it, still getting the same result. Any suggestions? P.S. the "response" in the code is an array with keys (products) and information of them (see screenshot). "response" is fetched from another file (.php).

Defining model:

```
  // Set up the model
  const model = {
    optimize: "price",
    opType: "min",
    constraints: {
      "calories": { "equal": userCalories }
    },
    variables: {}
  };

  console.log(response);

  // Set up the variables and the constraints in the model
  for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
    var name = response[i]['name'];
    //var price = parseFloat(response[i]['price'].replace(',', '.')); // Convert the price to a number
    model.variables[name] = {
      "price": parseFloat(response[i]['price'].replace(',', '.')),
      "calories": response[i]['calories']
    };
  }
  
  for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
    var name = response[i]['name'];
    model.constraints[name] = {};
    model.constraints[name][name] = 1;
  }
  
  model.constraints["use_all"] = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
    var name = response[i]['name'];
    model.constraints["use_all"][name] = 1;
  }

  
  // Solve the linear program
  const result = solver.Solve(model);
  console.log(result);
```

Result from this code:

[image]